# AWS DynamoDB Scan on Set attribute

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How does scan work with Set Attribute Type (NS or SS). I like to provide some condition for retrieve a Set. For eg: in Table I have

```
{Item1: Attr1{NS : 1,2,3,4,5}}
{Item2: Attr1{NS : 6,7,8}}
{item3: Attr1{NS : 7,10}}
```

I'd like to take the `Item2` and `Item3` by giving some scan condition. Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CONTAINS` or `NOT_CONTAINS` as the `ComparisonOperator` of the `ScanFilter` (more info here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Scan.html)

Eg:

```
{
  "TableName":"MyTable",
  "ScanFilter": {
    "Attr1": {
      "AttributeValueList": [{"N":"7"}],
      "ComparisonOperator": "CONTAINS"
    }
  }
}
```

This will return `Item2` and `Item3` because they both contain `7`.